Using Python read Refcursors returned from function in Postgres
I have a function that returns a set of refcursors:
CREATE function func_name(func_date date) returns SETOF refcursor
language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    ref1 refcursor := 'data_1';
    ref2 refcursor := 'data_2';
BEGIN 

    OPEN ref1 FOR
        SELECT * FROM users;
    RETURN NEXT ref1;

    OPEN ref2 FOR
        SELECT * FROM roles;
    RETURN NEXT ref2;
END;
$$;

I have the following code in Python which calls the function which returns a list of tuples of the refcursors. I need help as to how I can read these refcursors and add the data to a DataFrame
import psycopg2 as db
import datetime


# Connect to DB

conn = db.connect(host='abc', dbname='abc', user='a', password='abc',gssencmode="disable")
conn.set_session(autocommit=True)

func_date = datetime.date.today()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc('func_name', [func_date])
data = cur.fetchall()

for row in data:
    a = row[0]
    print(a)


Read the docs Server side cursors, the section starting: Note It is also possible to use a named cursor to consume a cursor created in some other way than using the DECLARE executed by execute(). For example, you may have a PL/pgSQL function returning a cursor:
